# Apps are installed in my smart phone without my permission?

Tags: applications, malware, antivirus

When wifi is on, Some strange applications are being installed automatically. I don't request them. They are downloaded without my permission. 
I uninstalled (removed) the unwanted apps from my smart phone. After a while, I found new unwanted apps in my phone. They are slowing down my cell phone and making it stuck. They also reserve or use my SD card and the internal memory of my phone.

I tried to fix this issue by editing (adjusting) the settings of my mobile but nothing happens.

I downloaded two antivirus softwares, They are avast and AVG, but nothing happens.

What should I do to prevent these apps from being installed on my phone? Is there a good app that controls or manage the downloaded apps?

By the way, yesterday, I found that mobile data is on without my permission and the unwanted apps were being downloaded. This costed me a lot of money.

How can I get rid of all of these problems?

Here is the specifications of my mobile: http://bestmobs.com/tecno-p5/

Thank you very much,

Comment: Backup what's important and factory reset. Flash stock firmware. Is your device rooted, just curious?

Comment: Have you seen [Apps install on their own](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46254/16575) (and similar questions)?

Comment: Appears to be this issue: [How to remove a Virus that installs an unlimited amount of APPs causing the smartphone to stop once an internet connection has been established?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/134927)

Comment: @AaronGillion I've made a factory reset but the issue still exists. My device is not rooted.

Comment: If you factory defaulted and still have apps installing on their own, they are probably being pushed from your Google Acct, which is the only way apps could be installing themselves on a clean phone. You should try not restoring apps and just install what is essential after a factory reset, if the problem persists then there is something in the system and it needs to be reflashed with the factory firmware image.

Comment: @lzzy AppCaster Is not on our home PC and I did Not you entered your Google credentials into another android phone. The answers of the question does not match my case.

Comment: @acejavelin Thank you very much, I will create another Google account.

Comment: May be [This thread](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134927/how-to-remove-a-virus-that-installs-an-unlimited-amount-of-apps-causing-the-smar) can help you.
Good Luck!