# Unwanted Apps (Maybe malware) downloaded and installed on Android device

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, malware, downloading

Off late, I have been observing some unwanted apps getting downloaded and installed on my Android device without my knowledge. Upon noticing I uninstalled those apps. However, the next time I switch on my data or connect to Wi-Fi, in no time does it re-install those apps. Is there a way in which I can troubelshoot this ?

Below are the couple of apps that are getting installed (please not none of these are available on Play Store):

- Content Visual
- VedioZone
- UC News
- WhatsApp (This is not the original WhatsApp with a slightly different icon)

I tried doing a Factory Reset with no success

I also tried resetting the device by going into the recovery mode with no success.

I disabled allowing apps to installed from unknown sources.

The Quick Heal anti-virus does not detect any threats.

Edit 1: I could see multiple instances of the above listed app as shown in below image:

[image: Settings --> Processes --> Running]

Comment: Have you checked [Apps install on their own](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46254/apps-install-on-their-own), [Apps are installed in my smart phone without my permission?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139613/apps-are-installed-in-my-smart-phone-without-my-permission?rq=1) and similar questions?

Comment: Yes, I did. Check my updated question.

Comment: @Yash I recommend you download and scan your phone with this anti malware: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.malwarebytes.antimalware It's free and worked great for me.

Comment: @Yash download and run a full system scan. You may also buy antivirus software like Quick heal if you like (I prefer free software a bit more, at least for my phone)

Comment: @WrichikBasu The majority of those "antivirus" apps for Android are mere scam, as far as I know.

Comment: Quick heal is not a scam, I can assure you. I have it on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I think some malicious process running on your device so go to

**Settings->App->Running (Tab)**

and try to identify unwanted process and if you get it stop the process and try to uninstall belonging application of respective process.

Comment: I could not find any suspicious processes running

Comment: OK,then try to install ES File explorer in that there is activity logger is there so you will able to see which app downloading what type of content so by this way may be you will get which app installing other apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is some kind of virus that has worked its way into the operating system. The only solution is to flash the default operating system again.

Since you did not specify the phone model, I'll be generic about my answer.

Reflashing the stock operating system is a process where you download the default operating system from the phone manufacturer website and load it into the phone, overwriting the existing operating system which is infected. A factory reset will not work in this case. Doing this involves unlocking the bootloader, which will void the warranty. Contact your phone's manufacturer and ask if there is a way to repair the phone without voiding the warranty. If there isn't, google your device name and "flash a custom ROM", or a custom operating system that many Android professionals prefer over the stock one. In your case, instead of writing the alternate operating system, we are simply rewriting the default one from the manufacturer.